# How to overlay a div over a canvas CSS

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to place a div over a canvas in HTML5 (as a HUD of sorts). I'm using `z-index`, it's not working. How can I achieve this using any CSS?

```
    .HUD {
        z-index:100;
    }

    canvas {
        z-index:1;
    }
```

Comment: `position: relative` or `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#container canvas, #overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <div id="overlay">This div is over the canvas</div>
</div>
```

We wrap the `canvas` and `div` in a container element, which is `position: relative`. Then the `canvas` and `div` are set to `position: absolute`.

Comment: This is a great answer... but... When I have a large `<div>` the canvas element bleeds right thru the div, no matter what the z-index, the background color or background-image?

Comment: I know that is an old topic, but maybe is someone who is hitting my problem. With soktinpk's code, my div situated in right of the canvas, when I am resizing my window, overlay the canvas. I resolve that with next portion of code: <div id="canvas-wrap">
    <div class="coord">
    </div>
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>. I moved my div before canvas and my css is .coord{position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;}

Comment: @zipzit:  I don't experience your problem, what do you mean by "bleed through"?

Comment: first person on SO to post an answer without javascript. this is helpful because for some reason R shiny is not giving an `id` attribute to canvas and so there is no selector.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
<div class="container_div" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="hover_div" style="position:absolute; width:25px !important; display:block;z-index:9999">                            
        <img class="some_class" src="/settings_icon.png" style="height: 20px; display: block;">
    </div>
<canvas width="180" height="270" style="width: 180px; height: 270px;"></canvas>
</div>
```