# Canvas in fullscreen hides my div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I am currently working on a 360-panorama project, using panolens.js and three.js. Panolens has a fullscreen mode, but the issue is that upon entering fullscreen mode, the canvas hides all my div elements. I have a text element displaying which image is loaded. I have tried to come up with solutions, such as creating text in the canvas itself, but that is quite difficult for me, since the canvas uses WebGL context. Could I get some help, or suggestions for any solutions? Thanks in advance.

[Here](http://joakimi.imkatta.no/projects/TG360) is my project containing the issue.

Comment: Did you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793247/how-to-overlay-a-div-over-a-canvas-css/26793302)? If that works, this is a duplicated question.

Comment: That's not the solution I'm looking for. I've tried solving the issue with some css, but to no luck. The canvas enters complete fullscreen mode, covering the entire screen, hiding other elements on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me if this could've been a comment, I don't have the reputation yet.

I found a [post](https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js/issues/117) with a similar issue to yours, and it was suggested there to put the element within the *panolens* container.

I tried it on your project using devtools, I took the element with the "#sceneName" id, and made it a child of the ".panolens-container" div, and it seemed to do the trick. So basically instead of the following structure:

```
<body>
    <center>
        <h1 id="sceneName">Hovedinngang</h1>
    </center>
    <div class="panolens-container" ...>
        <canvas/>
        ...
    </div>
<body>
```

this is the one that is required ( I didn't test this but perhaps the *center* tag can be moved here as well ):

```
<body>
    <div class="panolens-container" ...>
        <canvas/>
        <h1 id="sceneName">Hovedinngang</h1>
        ...
    </div>
<body>
```